# If you cancel the process of returning to the previous screen by swiping, the navigationBar remains without disappearing

Tags: swift, swiftui

When swiping from the View with navigationBarItems, canceling the swipe and returning to the previous screen, the navigationBar on the previous screen remained without disappearing.

Is this a bug?

Or is my implementation wrong?

You can check the phenomenon [here](https://s27.aconvert.com/convert/p3r68-cdx67/9o7th-fxf9s.gif).

```
struct TopView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Detail")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Top")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: EditView()) {
                Text("Edit")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Detail", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct EditView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Title")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Edit", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(
            trailing:
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

> @Environment (. PresentationMode) private var presentationMode:
>   Binding

If this were not present, it would not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fix

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: EditView()) {
                Text("Edit")         
            }.isDetailLink(false)                            // << here !!
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Detail", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```